# I want to remove an element from an string array if the string exist in other element in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to remove an element in an array if it appears within, or is contained in any other element within the same array.

## For Example:

```js
const arr = ["Hello" , "Hell" , "Lower" , "Low", "Hii"];
```

## Target output:

```js
["Hello" , "Lower", "Hii]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried writing code for this? Please share your attempt at solving it yourself. Thanks.

Comment: And where exactly are you stuck in your code?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this way with array [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
 and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set),

```js
const arr = ["Hello", "Hell", "Lower", 'Lo', "Low", "Hii"];
const expected = [];
arr.forEach(function(element) {
  el = arr.find(a => a.includes(element));
  expected.push(el);
})

console.log([...new Set(expected)]);
```